# Android OpenGL - glTexImage2D causing crash using ByteBuffer wrapped over byte[] with offset

Tags: android, opengl-es, bytebuffer, glteximage2d

*Problem:* Passing a `ByteBuffer` wrapping a `byte[]` containing image data into `GLES20.glTexImage2D(...)` is working for me if and only if the `ByteBuffer` has **no offset** - otherwise (if there's an offset set) it crashes unhelpfully with something like:

```
Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x61616162636575 in tid 32016 (GLThread 4912), pid 31806
```

---

*Background:* I have a single `byte[]` of YUV (I420) data for a 720p image - and I need to read this out as 3 separate `ByteBuffer`s to pass to an OpenGL shader which has 3 different sampler2D channels (1 channel per buffer).

Ideally, since all the information is there in memory, I would create three ByteBuffers wrapping different parts of the `byte[]` like this:

```
ByteBuffer yBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(rawYUVData, 0, yBufferSize);
ByteBuffer uBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(rawYUVData, yBufferSize, uBufferSize);
ByteBuffer vBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(rawYUVData, yBufferSize+uBufferSize, uBufferSize);
```

And then in my renderer code, I call OpenGL `glTexImage2D` three times also:

```
GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, yTexDataHandle);
GLES20.glTexImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GLES20.GL_LUMINANCE, imgWidth, imgHeight, 0, GLES20.GL_LUMINANCE, GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, yBuffer);

GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, uTexDataHandle);
GLES20.glTexImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GLES20.GL_LUMINANCE, uWidth, uHeight, 0, GLES20.GL_LUMINANCE, GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, uBuffer);

GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, vTexDataHandle);
GLES20.glTexImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GLES20.GL_LUMINANCE, uWidth, uHeight, 0, GLES20.GL_LUMINANCE, GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, vBuffer);
```

This is crashing. I can fix the crash just fine by copying the contents of the above `uBuffer` and `vBuffer` into new `byte[]`s, then rewrapping the `ByteBuffer`s over the new arrays.

But I'm copying data needlessly, and 30x per second.

Can I not wrap `ByteBuffer`s over the contiguous byte[], with offsets, and use these in OpenGL for some reason? Do I really have to copy all the time?

- I've checked it's not an issue in my shader file, by removing the calls to `texture2D()` that involve the offending samplers.
- Even just adding an offset of 1 to my construction of `yBuffer`, and it crashes where with 0 it works fine. (rawYUVData.length is always > yBufferSize + 1)

Comment: Potentially useful comment - if instead of a `byte[]`-backed `ByteBuffer`, I have a _direct_ `ByteBuffer` - then I can use offset buffer slices for OpenGL texturing, just fine. The problem only exists when the original backing data is a Java `byte[]`.